# Magento 2 - Update product collection price and reset collection

Tags: magento2, price, magento2.2, product-collection, object

I want to update product price from the collection and use that collection again. I have written a code for that as per below:

```
$price = 23;
foreach ($this->_collection as $key => $value) {
    $value->setPrice($price);
    $sin = $value;
    $this->_collection->removeItemByKey($value->getId());   //I have tried to remove a object
    $this->_collection->addItem($sin);  //set a value again with updated price in a object
}    
print_r($this->_collection);exit;    
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),
    $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```

But In Results when I print collection then the price is not updating the collection.

Comment: You can assign collection to other variable before iterate collection and make changes in it.

Comment: @ChiragRajput can you please give me an example for that.?

Comment: $price = 23;
$ccollection = $this->_collection;
foreach ($this->_collection as $key => $value) {
    $value->setPrice($price);
    $sin = $value;
    $this->_collection->removeItemByKey($value->getId());   //I have tried to remove a object
    $this->_collection->addItem($sin);  //set a value again with updated price in a object
}    
print_r($this->_collection);exit;    
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),
    $this->getCurrentDirection());
}

IN the above way you can save collection in other variable

Comment: @ChiragRajput In your given code, you have assign collection to other variable but you did not use that anywhere. Then whats the purpose to assign a collection to other variables?